# How to document LaTeX custom packages and document classes?

Tags: package-writing, documentclass-writing

While I can use something like Doxygen to document a C library (functions, constants and structures defined/written by me), I couldn't find something equivalent in LaTeX to document \newcommand(s) \let(s) and other stuff in my .cls and .sty files.

Since LaTeX is common used as output (even by Doxygen), I'm struggling to find "Google keywords" for this specific matter.

Am I supposed to document a class/package by creating a separate LaTeX file specific for this? Or maybe, is literal programming the recommended way for LaTeX?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.texdev.net/2009/10/06/a-model-dtx-file/

Comment: Using `.dtx` file is recommended, but AFAIK many people use the normal `.tex` file to write a documentation (even for many popular packages).